# If an Image placed into a Grid, the part of image below Grid.Bottom goes lost

Tags: c#, wpf, image, transform

I'll try to be short. So, in XAML:

```
<Grid Height="100" Width="100" ClipToBounds="True">
  <Image  Width="100" Height="200" Name="image" Stretch="None" Source="/Test;component image.png" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
      <TranslateTransform x:Name="transform" X="0" Y="0"/>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
  </Image>
</Grid>
```

if now we change image position using transform in code:

```
transform.Y -= 50;
```

, the image moves 50 pixels up, but is cut to 100 pixels.

Why we do not see the whole part of the image (y from 50 to 150)?

Comment: I assume because of ClipToBounds="True" the image will be cut before TranslateTransform.

Comment: but if I write in XAML <Image ...Margin="0,-100,0,0..., and <TranslateTransform... Y="100", I have what I want. So, I can achieve what I should, but I want to understand this interesting behaviour.